# Hicer un programa que ordena areglos de cadenas en c++, pero no funciona

Tags: c++, string, punteros, recursión

Hice un programa para ordenar cadenas en c++ con el algoritmo quick sort y funciones recursivas y con punteros. El programa tiene 2 funciones void con parametros y una de ellas usa una funcion de recursion toda la sintaxis parece estar correcta pero al momento de ejecutarlo no imprime nada, y no tengo idea del error que tengo.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;
void intercambio(char x[70],char y[70])
{
    char aux[70];

    strcpy(aux,x);
    strcpy(x,y);
    strcpy(y,aux);
}
void quicksort (char (*a)[70],int izquierda, int derecha)
{
    int i,j,central; //declaramos los iteradores, y el central
    char pivote[70]; // el pivote va a ser la posicion inicial

    central=(izquierda+derecha)/2; //La posicion del arreglo central
    strcpy(pivote,a[central]);  //pivote es el valor de la posicion central
    i=izquierda; //i es igual a la posicion inicial del arreglo
    j=derecha; //i es igual a la posicion final del arreglo

    do{
            while(strcmpi(a[i],pivote)<0){i++;}
            while(strcmpi(a[j],pivote)>0){i++;}

            if(i>=j)
            {
            intercambio(a[i],a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
            }
            if(izquierda<=i)
            {
                quicksort(&a[70],izquierda,j);
            }
            if(i<derecha)
            {
                quicksort(&a[70],i,derecha);
            }


    }while(i<=j);
}
int main()
{
    char cadena[70][70];
    int n,c=0;

    cout<<"Introduzca el numero de elementos del arreglo: "; cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    cout<<"Ingrese el valor de la posicion "<<i+1<<": "; cin.getline(cadena[i],70,'\n');

    }

    quicksort(&cadena[70],c,n-1);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    cout<<i+1<<"-"<<cadena[i]<<endl;

    }



    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&cadena[70]` te da la dirección de memoria del elemento en la posición 70 del arreglo. Las posiciones comienzan desde el 0 y tus arreglos son de 70 elementos así que no es válido. Además puedes usar simplemente enteros en lugar de punteros para `primero` y `ultimo`. Está difícil interpretar lo que quisiste hacer. Sugiero que primero implementes quicksort para números y luego te ayudamos a implementarlo para cadenas.

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos errores en el código que estás presentando. A continuación, te describo algunos de ellos:

En la función quicksort, en la línea while(strcmpi(a[i],pivote)<0){i++;}, la variable i se está incrementando sin control, lo que puede generar un bucle infinito. En su lugar, deberías poner una condición para que el bucle termine cuando se cumpla que strcmpi(a[i],pivote) sea mayor o igual a cero.

En la misma función quicksort, en la línea while(strcmpi(a[j],pivote)>0){i++;}, estás incrementando la variable i en lugar de la variable j. Deberías cambiar i++ por j--.

En la línea if(izquierda<=i), debes tener cuidado con el uso de los operadores de comparación. En este caso, el operador correcto es < y no <=.

En la línea if(i<derecha), nuevamente debes tener cuidado con el uso de los operadores de comparación. En este caso, el operador correcto es > y no <.

En las líneas quicksort(&a[70],izquierda,j); y quicksort(&a[70],i,derecha);, estás pasando un parámetro incorrecto a la función quicksort. En lugar de pasar &a[70], deberías pasar simplemente a.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

// Función para intercambiar dos cadenas
void intercambio(char x[70],char y[70])
{
    char aux[70];

    strcpy(aux, x);
    strcpy(x, y);
    strcpy(y, aux);
}

// Función que implementa el algoritmo QuickSort para ordenar un arreglo de cadenas
void quicksort(char (*a)[70], int izquierda, int derecha)
{
    int i, j, central;
    char pivote[70];

    central = (izquierda + derecha) / 2;
    strcpy(pivote, a[central]);
    i = izquierda;
    j = derecha;

    do
    {
        while (strcmpi(a[i], pivote) < 0) i++;
        while (strcmpi(a[j], pivote) > 0) j--;

        if (i >= j)
        {
            intercambio(a[i], a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        if (izquierda < j)
        {
            quicksort(a, izquierda, j);
        }
        if (i < derecha)
        {
            quicksort(a, i, derecha);
        }
    } while (i <= j);
}

int main()
{
    char cadena[70][70];
    int n, c = 0;

    cout << "Introduzca el numero de elementos del arreglo: ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor de la posicion " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(cadena[i], 70, '\n');
    }

    quicksort(cadena, c, n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "-" << cadena[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```